# Reviving an old laptop

Tags: laptop, upgrade

I have a Toshiba Tecra A4 laptop (Model: PTA40A-1D2004) that was top notch in it's day. Now it's slow and behind the times :(

I want to add a bit of RAM and a bigger HDD to give it a new life, possibly with a Windows 7 and/or Linux update to give it a second life. I know from previous experience there are limits to the amount of upgrading that can be done due to physical limitations of the form factor and BIOS.

How do I find out what would be the biggest HDD and RAM module that will be accepted without trial and error?

Current specs:-

- Intel Centrino (Pentium-M) 1.86GHz Processor
- 512MB RAM
- nVidea GeForce 6600 graphics
- 80GB HDD
- Windows XP

Comment: Not asked (and thus not in the answer). Consider a SSD.  If you do not store movies on the laptop then a SSD will make it much faster and when you upgrade to your next laptop you can take the SSD with you. It made a lot of difference with my old Tecra S4.

Comment: I didn't ask about SSD's as I am not considdering SSD's since I do use the laptop as a portable movie player.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I find out what would be the biggest HDD and RAM module that will be accepted without trial and error?

Is a bit to specific. I hope you do not mind if I answer this in general, so other readers also can apply that for their laptop models.

**Lets start with the harddisk:**

1) Your laptop uses a  <strike>[SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) harddisk. There are currently three SATA standards, but they are all backwards compatible. Therefore any SATA harddisk currently on the market can be used.</strike>

ERROR: That was the wrong model. The tecra **A4** has **IDE**.  Drives do get faster per generation, but I can't find any recent IDE drives. Which means you are probably stuck with the current drive or an expensive upgrade to a 320GB-ish drive from a few years ago. This is probably not worth it.

2) The harddisk partitioning scheme used on most older computers is MBR. This has a limit of 2.19TiB.  You will need to partition the drive differently to use a larger drive.

For PC style hardware this is usually done by partitioning it with [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). Not every BIOS understands GPT, which means that for an older computer you usually can not boot from a GPT partitioned disk.

Thus you need any SATA HDD up to 2.19TiB.

**Next, the memory.**

The maximum amount of memory you can use is limited by:

- The CPU (which these days holds the memory controller)
- The chipset (esp. older ones which contained the memory controller)
- The number of copper traces on the motherboard. (Cheaper to lay less traces. The manufacturer will usually use enough to satisfy most of the market. More just isn't economical)
- The available memory modules. Both their maximum size,and number of memory slots.

Your laptop has an [Pentium-M 750](http://ark.intel.com/products/27328/Mobile-Intel-Celeron-Processor-750-MHz-128K-Cache-100-MHz-FSB)
 which can address up to 32bit (4GiB).
Your chipset is an http://ark.intel.com/products/27717/Intel-82915PM-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller">Intel 915PM. This one has a max memory limit of 2 GB.

You can only use the lesser of these two. Your are limited 2 GB.

A sanity check on your motherboard shows that it indeed allows up to 2GB, using DDR SODIMM's at 333MHz ( PC2700 ). You will DDR(1) [SoDIMMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC2700). DDR2 and DD3 will neither fit, nor will they work it you fit them with help of a hammer.

Comment: I took my HDD out - looks like an IDE drive to me!

Comment: *double checks*.  My mistake. I had the tecra S4 manual in front of me when looking at the drives. That rather limits drive upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

The most important is the spec of your motherboard or the at least the type of chipset your motherboard use. this rules device support.

From the info your put, I guess it's reasonable to enlarge mem to 1G/1.5G by adding another 512mb/1gb ram(the laptop usually has only 2 mem slots). and the size of hdd may be enlarged to 160GB? it depends on if you can get a 2.5" **IDE** HDD in that size.

Best practice is to get a light linux distro(e.g. puppylinux), and you can use it as a router or movieplayer or typewriter ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going into as much detail as the thorough answer from Hennes.

Regarding only the hard disk, there's also another possibility.
As it is said [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-laptop-upgrade-optical-bay,3102.html) you may remove your dvd bay and install a hard disk or SSD instead. There are different kits at sale, for different prices.

I could not find out whether your disk is SATA or not. If it is, you may buy a SSD disk for the OS and another disk to be put in the optical bay.

This means you will have to use an external dvd drive whenever you need it.